# Can you force the wspace and hspace of figure subplots to a fixed value in matplotlib regardless of figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, figure, imshow

I am trying to build a function to plot multiple images in a grid with a single colorbar and histogram. I would like the spacing between all the plots to be a fixed value and for the colorbar to span the height of a all images and histogram to span the width of the images/colorbar.  I have some code that works, but it requires the figure size being set to a specific aspect ratio for it to work.  This is not ideal because I want to use the function for images with varying aspect ratios and for a varying number of images 2x1, 1x2, 2x2, etc.

This code outputs 3 figures of varying aspect ratio.  I would like if any excess dimension would be applied to the border spacing rather than the subplot wspace, hspace spacing.

fig wide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB1Cz.png

fig tall: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5C34.png

fig nice: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVX6C.png

Here is the code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def compare_frames(frames, columns, bins=256, alpha=.5, vmin=None, vmax=None, fig=None):
    if vmin is None:
        vmin = min([f.min() for f in frames])
    if vmax is None:
        vmax = max([f.max() for f in frames])
    if fig == None:
        fig = plt.figure()
    color_cycle = plt.get_cmap('tab10')
    rows = math.ceil(len(frames)/columns)
    width_ratios = [1 for col in range(columns)] + [.05]
    
    gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(rows + 1, columns + 1, figure=fig, width_ratios=width_ratios)
    images = []
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(columns):
            idx = row*columns + col
            if idx < len(frames):
                ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[row, col])
                ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
                ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
                for spine in ['bottom', 'top', 'left', 'right']:
                    ax.spines[spine].set_color(color_cycle(idx))
                    ax.spines[spine].set_linewidth(3)
                images.append(ax.imshow(frames[idx], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
    
    cax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:-1, -1])
    plt.colorbar(images[0], cax=cax)

    hax = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1, :])
    for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
        hax.hist(frame.ravel(), bins=256, range=(vmin, vmax), color=color_cycle(i), alpha=alpha)
    
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.05, hspace=.05)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_size = 640
    y_size = 512
    frames = []
    for i in range(4):
        frames.append(np.random.normal(i + 1, np.sqrt(i + 1), size=(y_size, x_size)))
    
    fig_wide = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    compare_frames(frames, 2, fig=fig_wide)
    fig_tall = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 8))
    compare_frames(frames, 2, fig=fig_tall)
    fig_nice = plt.figure(figsize=(6.9, 8))
    compare_frames(frames, 2, fig=fig_nice)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you need the aspect ratio of the “images” to be one-to-one?   If so, then you are asking for something that is relatively difficult to do generally.  Specifically, you can of course just place the axes manually using set_position

Comment: Yes, I need to preserve the aspect row of the images.  The real-world images I will use are camera sensor data which I want to preserve the aspect ratio.  I will not mix up the aspect ratios of the images however (all frames I am comparing will have identical aspect ratio)

Answer (score 0):

I've gathered that I should probably be using matplotlib axes_grid1 from mpl_toolkits.  They have a built-in ImageGrid class which does a lot of what I would like to do (fixed spacing for images and colorbar):

```
def compare_frames(frames, columns, bins=256, alpha=.5, vmin=None, vmax=None, fig=None):
    if vmin is None:
        vmin = min([f.min() for f in frames])
    if vmax is None:
        vmax = max([f.max() for f in frames])
    if fig == None:
        fig = plt.figure()
    color_cycle = plt.get_cmap('tab10')
    rows = math.ceil(len(frames)/columns)
    
    im_grid = axes_grid1.ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(rows, columns), axes_pad=.1,
        cbar_mode='single', cbar_pad=.1, cbar_size=.3)
    for i, ax in enumerate(im_grid):
        im = ax.imshow(frames[i], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
        ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
        ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
        for spine in ['bottom', 'top', 'left', 'right']:
            ax.spines[spine].set_color(color_cycle(i))
            ax.spines[spine].set_linewidth(3)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=im_grid.cbar_axes[0])
```

This is great, and I would love to figure out a way to use this ImageGrid class to do most of the work, and then add another axis at the bottom for the histogram.  I haven't been able to crack how to do this however since all of the examples I've found use "append_axes()" on a Divider class. ImageGrid forms a SubplotDivider however, which doesn't have an append_axes function.